# Getting Login failed for user ~NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON~ after upgrading to .NET 4.0

Tags: vb.net

Getting Login failed for user ~NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON~ after upgrading to .NET 4.0

a few seconds ago|LINK

I have a visual 2005 web application (version .NET 2.0). I am able to login to the database and open a connection. I upgraded my project to .NET 4.0 and ran the same project again. After I enter my userId, I get the "Login failed for user ~NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON~" error.  I am not sure what is causing the error. When it gets to the con.Open() line, it throws an exception. Any help is appreciated.

```
    Public Shared Function GetUserMenuItems(ByVal userId As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim con As SqlConnection = Db.DataAccess.GetAdminSqlConnection()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("uspGetUserMenuItems", con)

        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            With .Parameters
                .Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = userId
            End With
        End With

        Try
            con.Open()
            dt = Db.DataAccess.GetDataTable(cmd, "Validations")

            Return dt

        Catch err As Exception
            Throw err
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
            cmd.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Function
```

Connection string is

Comment: Did you previously have a specific user to log in to SQL Server, or were you using `integrated security=true`? Have you moved the web application to a new server to go along with updating it to .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Your username and password should be in your connection string.  You are passing the userid as a parameter, the open connection needs the correct configuration to open the connection in the first place.